# print out the content of __m256i variable

Tags: c++, windows, x86, simd, avx

I am trying to print out the value of an `__m256i` variable but I get a run-time error (file.exe has stopped working!). My CPU is Intel and supports AVX instructions. When I comment the cout line, the code runs. I am using Intel C++ compiler. what is the problem? Is there any other way to show the contents of `__m256i` variable. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "immintrin.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    __m256i a;
    int i;

    a = _mm256_set_epi64x(1, 2, 3, 4);

    cout << setfill('0'); // fill with 0s

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        cout << hex << setw(16) << _mm256_extract_epi64(a, i);

    }

    cout << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was it actually compiled to? Especially that extract, which is impossible without unrolling the loop

Comment: Yes, It is compiled without any problem. By the way, the problem is with the cout not the extract instruction. The code does not work without the loop either (e.g. i = 0).

Comment: Intel ICC (17 or 18) does not even compile this (on Linux at least). clang is the only compiler I have found that will unroll the loop to get compile-time constants for the extract index. What version of ICC are you using ?

Comment: I use nodepad to type the code and then I use the ICC 18 to compile it (e.g. icl test.cpp) and then I run the exe file. My OS is windows 10 64bit. Anyway, is there any other way to show the content of the variable a?

Comment: If you are using the [G2020 the spec sheet](https://ark.intel.com/products/71070/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G2020-3M-Cache-2_90-GHz) shows it doesn't support AVX. It only supports Intel® SSE4.1, Intel® SSE4.2 extensions.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I used coreinfo.exe and it says it supports AVX. Perhaps this is the reason of the run-time error. I will run my code on my friend's computer on saturday and I will update the question.

Comment: UPDATE: my code runs correctly on my friend's computer. The CPU of his computer is Intel Core i5 3570. I wonder why coreinfo.exe reports that my CPU (Intel G2020) supports AVX. Thank you all for the comments anyway.

Comment: I have just found a code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx which reports the supported CPU instruction sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use next function to print content of __m256i vector:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>    

template<class T> inline void Log(const __m256i & value)
{
    const size_t n = sizeof(__m256i) / sizeof(T);
    T buffer[n];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)buffer, value);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << buffer[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    __m256i a = _mm256_set_epi64x(1, 2, 3, 4);
    Log<long>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the same run-time error with this code too. Perhaps the problem is related to my CPU. My CPU is Intel G2020.

Comment: Is `long long` missing parentheses?

Comment: Or you meant to use `(T)`instead of `long long`

Comment: CPU G2020 does not support AVX or AVX2.

Comment: Related: [print a \_\_m128i variable](//stackoverflow.com/a/46752535) for more about why storing to a tmp array is a good thing, and why it wouldn't be safe to do pointer-casting.